# Symfony 2 : render(controller()) ask for an argument ... that I gave

Tags: symfony, controller, production-environment

I have a weird problem in prod environment (not happening in dev).

I display a contact form from my twig template like that :

```
{{ render_esi( controller( "sise_contact:contactPageAction", {'initialRequest' : app.request, 'location': location}) ) }}
```

The problem is that in prod env, the form does not display at all. There is the log error :

> [2013-07-08 16:50:58] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   RuntimeException: "Controller
>   "Sise\ContactBundle\Controller\DefaultController::contactPageAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$initialRequest" argument
>   (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional
>   argument after this one)." at
>   /var/www/gii/sise/application/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
>   line 134 [] []

As I said, it does work in dev environment.

I did clear my prod cache but it does nothing.

Do you have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue discussed here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10524

In **development**, it isn't a *true* sub-request that is performed, instead, the controller is directly called with the parameters passed as is.

In **production**, a true sub-request is created by generating a URI. For this URI to be generated, all the arguments must be scalars in order to be incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible to pass objects when using `render_esi`